# splitting of xml file using c#

Tags: c#

I am using c# and am creating xml from an external data source and saving the xml as a single xml file.  How can I split the xml up and save it as multiple xml files?  For example, say there are 263 records in my xdocument xml.  I need to split that into multiple xml files containing exactly 25 records.  (That's the specs - no way around it.)  So, for this example, I'd end up with 11 xml files.

My data source is a XML file , and I have the option of splitting that into chunks of 25 records per XML file, if that is easier.  How would I approach doing it that way?

Comment: The specs need to be *slightly* more generous than that - you *can't* split 263 records into files containing *exactly* 25 records, unless you're happy to either skip some or duplicate some. Are you allowed to make the final file contain fewer than 25 records? It's also not clear how your second paragraph is different to your first...

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this:

```
string xml=@"<a>
     <b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/>
     <b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/>
     <b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/>
     <b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/><b/>
    </a>";

int itemsPerDoc = 25;

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XDocument> newDocs=
    xDoc
        .Root
        //grab all immediate child elements of root (named "b")
        .Elements("b") 
        //use integer division to create a group "number"
        //so groups of 25 items will share same group "number"
        .Select((e,i) => new {g = i/itemsPerDoc, e}) 
        //use group "number" to perform grouping
        .GroupBy(x => x.g)
        //now we have groups of 25, use these 25 items
        //to project into a new document containing the items
        .Select(gr => {
            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Parse("<newDoc/>");
            newDoc.Root.Add(gr.Select(p => p.e));
            return newDoc;
        });
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<XDocument>` where each document contains 25 (or less in the case of the last doc) children of the original `XDocument`.

Comment: Whilst this looks like it would work for the OP, you might want to add some explanation as to what and how it is doing it.

Comment: @Grhm: I added some comments to shed some light.